# Why am I getting an error when using 'squeeze' keyword in 'read_csv'?

Tags: pandas, series

```
alcohol = pd.read_csv('https://andybek.com/pandas-drinks', usecols=['country','wine_servings'], index_col='country', squeeze=True)
```

When using the keyword `squeeze` to convert a one columned dataframe to series, I'm getting an error `TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'squeeze'`.

Answer (score 5):

`read_csv` no longer has a `squeeze` parameter. It was removed [in Pandas 2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

> - Removed arguments ..., `squeeze`, ... from [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) (..., [GH43427](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43427))

Instead use [`DataFrame.squeeze('columns')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) after reading the CSV.